# How To Get Text From "A" Tag - Python Selenium (Categories, Subcategories, Sub-subcategories)

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I need to get parent categories, subcategories and sub-subcategories. I'm getting the items in the main category without any problems. While retrieving the elements in the subcategory, I can capture the Selenium element, but the text is coming empty. What should I do?

My Python codes:

```python
mainCategories = driver.find_element(By.ID, "mainMenu").find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "li[class='categories']")

for i in mainCategories:

    subCategories = i.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "li[class='subs']")

    for j in subCategories:
        print("j = ", j)              # it returns Selenium elements and its length matches the subcategories. 
        print("j.text = ", j.text)    # it returns ""
```

My Html like this:

```html
<div id="mainMenu">
    <li class="categories">
        <a href="#">Main Category 1</a>
        <div class="subMenu">
            <div class="col">
                <div class="col-2">
                    ...
                    <li class="subs">
                        <a>Subcategory 1</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li class="row"><a href="#">Sub-subcategory 1</a></li>
                            <li class="row"><a href="#">Sub-subcategory 2</a></li>
                            ... Other Sub-subcategories' li's ...
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    ... Other Subcategories' li's ...
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
    ... Other Main Categories' li's ...
</div>
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: You should not use tag name like this `li[class='subs']`, it more looks like a CSS selector than a `tag_name`

Answer (score 0):

The texts of sub categories is presented in `a` elements below the `li` elements you are locating.
Please try this, it should give you sub categories texts:

```py
mainCategories = driver.find_element(By.ID, "mainMenu").find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "li[class='categories']")

for i in mainCategories:

    subCategories = i.find_elements(By.XPATH, ".//li[@class='subs']/a")

    for j in subCategories:
        print("j = ", j)
        print("j.text = ", j.text)
```